# Самопроизвольное изменение пути при сохранении файла в Android 6.0.1

Tags: java, android, файлы

Сохраняю файл так:

```
File filesDir = getFilesDir();
File myFile = new File(filesDir, "MyFile.jpg");
os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

В `myFile` хранится адрес:

```
/data/user/0/my.package.name/files/MyFile.jpg
```

Но по факту файл почему-то сохраняется по адресу

```
/data/data/my.package.name/files/MyFile.jpg
```

Как такое может быть?

Воспроизводится под Android 6.0.1

Comment: на мой взгляд у вас все работает именно так как вы ему и сказали)) я говорю о том что вы сказали приложению сохранить файл в папку приложения в подпапку файлов, оно туда и сохраняет, не очень понятна строка - `В myFile хранится адрес` что вы здесь имели в виду?

Comment: Я имел в виду `absolutePath`.

Comment: а попробуйте `this.getFilesDir().toString()` что оно выведет в логи например

Comment: Выводит `/data/user/0/my.package.name/files`.

Comment: а если так  получить эту папку - `ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()` что оно выведет

Comment: @Streletz, а если проверить путь методом `getCanonicalPath()`? Путь может содержать ссылку (не помню символьная или жёсткая в данном случае - можете погуглить по теме, если интересно) - и тогда два пути и более могут указывать на один и тот же файл. Но, как уже сказали ниже, лучше всегда формировать путь к приватным файлам и папкам с помощью контекста, а не жёстко прописанными путями.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно хранить полный путь к файлу! Т.к. исходя из описания используемого метода путь может быть изменён.

`/**
     * Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files
     * created with {@link #openFileOutput} are stored.
     * <p>
     * The returned path may change over time if the calling app is moved to an
     * adopted storage device, so only relative paths should be persisted.
     * <p>
     * No additional permissions are required for the calling app to read or
     * write files under the returned path.
     *
     * @return The path of the directory holding application files.
     * @see #openFileOutput
     * @see #getFileStreamPath
     * @see #getDir
     */
    public abstract File getFilesDir();`

Comment: А, как тогда получить фактическое расположение файла?

Comment: @Streletz, Andrew Goroshko писал, что выведит в лог команда: ContextWrapper.getFilesDir(). Предполагаю что именно так вы можете получить начальный путь на каждом устройстве, а концовку пишите ту которая будет вашей душе угодная. P.S. Поексперементируйте с получением пути разными командами. Ведьт все устройства разные и у каждого путь может отличаться.

Comment: @Streletz просто каждый раз используйте связку имени файла и метода getFilesDir(). File myFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "MyFile.jpg");